# How to format a moment date with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs with moment.

I need format a moment date.

Moment is installed correctly and working.

I have a variable mydate showing below.

My code is:

```
$scope.mylabel= moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

After that, I get $scope.mylabel= 'invalid date'

What am I doing wrong?

mydate is:

```
{date: r, mdp: {…}, selectable: true, $$hashKey: "object:156"}
$$hashKey:
"object:156"
date:
r
_d:Fri Nov 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão) {}
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:false
_isValid:true
```

**The complete code is:**

I am using the next widget:

```
https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker
```

//markup

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <multiple-date-picker  calendar-id="'myId2'" ng-model="myDate" 
    day-click="oneDaySelectionOnly"></multiple-date-picker>
</div>
```

//controller

```
angular.module("clinang")
.controller('agendaGeralController'......
 $scope.myDate = [];
 $scope.myDate.push(moment());
 $scope.oneDaySelectionOnly = function (event, date) {
    $scope.mylabel= moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    //I also tried date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') and both result in "invalid date")
    $scope.myDate.length = 0;
};
]);
```

Comment: can you do one thing for us? var myDate = new Date(date); see what myDate returns

Comment: var myDate = new Date(date);  returns 'invalid date' because date is a moment date.

Comment: I am sure the `date` is not a valid date that's why you getting this error.

Comment: I am using this widget from https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker. <div class="col-sm-3">
    <multiple-date-picker  calendar-id="'myId2'" ng-model="myDate" 
        day-click="oneDaySelectionOnly"></multiple-date-picker>
</div>. So, I believe  the date comimg from widget to my controller function is correct.

Comment: @Mikas Yes I did.

Comment: var now = moment('Fri Nov 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 Above code returns - 2017-11-09.
Make sure you are passing the data to moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you `moment.js` is added and date is a valid date, you should get the desired output as

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = '2012-11-20';
    $scope.formattedDate = moment($scope.date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div>
            Non-Formatted Date : {{date}}
            <br><br>
            Formatted Date: {{formattedDate}}
        </div>
      
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I use moment.js in all my controllers. It´s is correct. My problem is with that code posted above.  There is a problem in other place.

Comment: I've used exactly the same code. Can you please tell me what's the value of `date` in your case ?

Comment: Can I post the complete code? I have put only a snippet.

Comment: yeah.. that would be much helpful

Comment: I just solved it. I have to use date.date in my function. Thanks everybody for all.

Comment: That's good. you should try `day-click="oneDaySelectionOnly($event, myDate)"` too. that should work I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159255/discussion-between-usman-rana-and-luiz-alves).